# AFrame - updating an element's matrix

Tags: three.js, aframe

Recently started using Aframe and Three.js and I am trying to update the matrix of an element from my Aframe scene using the following three.js code:

```
this.el.object3D.matrix.fromArray(someLength16FloatArray)
```

But it doesn't seem to work even though if I declare a matrix4 and call it say "m", and use the fromArray() as in the code below to update m, it works.

```
m.fromArray(someLength16FloatArray)
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works only if the matrixAutoUpdate property of the element's object3D is set to false.

```
this.el.object3D.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
```